# Does archiving a registration form in CommCare affect the the other forms submitted to that case?

Tags: commcare

I have a registration form that has been successfully submitted for a case in CommCare as well as several other forms that have been submitted against that case. If I archive the registration form will that action affect the other data already submitted and synced against this case? How will archiving this form affect that case's data?

Answer (score 1):

Archiving any form causes CommCareHQ to rebuild any cases affected as if that form had never been submitted.  So, if you archive a registration form, it actually un-opens that case and it's like that case never existed.

Archiving a registration form when there are follow-up forms submitted can therefore cause problems, as it leaves a bunch of forms that are applied to a case that never existed.

There is a new change to CommCareHQ which should no longer allow you to archive a registration form when other forms exist for that case, thus preventing the problems described above.  Now, if you want to delete a case, you have two options:

1. Archive all follow-up forms and then archive the registration form. This will also delete all of the form data.
2. Assign that case to a temporary user (say username Delete).  Then delete user Delete.  This will delete the case but not the form data.

**Disclaimer:  Always be very careful about deleting any data off of CommCare.  It is not always possible to recover data if you delete something accidentally.**